# Split url on both ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, split

I have a url like this:

```
http://mywebsite.nl/url?q=http://SomeWebsite.com/&sa=U&ei=nszMUIi_GOm-0QXV-IGgDA&ved=0CBgQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHaN4L8nQBIDfpgcOpD0hCsEuI1vA
```

I would like to clean up the url by splitting it in 3 sections and keep the middle part. I know how to split and get rid of the first part like this:

```
var href =  $(this).attr('href'); 
    url  = href.split('='); 
    url  = url[1];
```

The broblem is that I also would like to get rid of the last part, which would be like this:

```
var href =  $(this).attr('href'); 
    url  = href.split('&'); 
    url  = url[0];
```

This way a clean url would be left:

```
http://SomeWebsite.com/
```

How do I combine the splitting parts in to one single code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Z5nkR/1/)**

```
str = "http://mywebsite.nl/url?q=http://SomeWebsite.com/&sa=U&ei=nszMUIi_GOm-0QXV-IGgDA&ved=0CBgQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHaN4L8nQBIDfpgcOpD0hCsEuI1vA";
resultUrl = str.split('=')[1].split('/&sa')[0];
```

Comment: Would this be better than above anwser?

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
var href = (this.getAttribute("href").match(/=(.*?)&/) || ["",""])[1];
```

Comment: Hi, it seems to be working:) Thank you very much. I don't know javascript so it looks alien to me, thats why "not like that"